# Why can't I access my modem configuration page?

Tags: networking, home-networking, modem

I was trying to access modem configuration page. But it's showing "Page Cannot be reached", tried in Edge, Chrome, and Firefox browsers.

Default Gateway:

[image]

Nmap:

[image]

Comment: Try wired Ethernet. Having the admin page accessible over WiFi is a security risk.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I don't most routers and/or gateway modems differentiate between LAN and WLAN clients when it comes down to the configuration page.  What is more likely is the configuration page has been disabled or the gateway is in a mode that makes it inaccessible.

Comment: idk. Mine is set to internal wired LAN only, no other way in from outside or inside. [It can be unlocked to both WiFi & WAN, but I choose not to].

Comment: @Tetsujin  I tried to access through wired connection but no luck. The pages keeps on loading finally it’s showing  “THE CONNECTION HAS TIMED OUT”. Any other way to access mu modem settings other than modem reset.